# Prevent mist from downloading geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, parity

I'm running Manjaro Linux (based on Arch), so I already have very up-to-date system versions of `geth` and `parity`.

I want to use my system `geth` without being forced to download another copy.

Alternately, I may not want to have `geth` on my system at all, using a `parity` node with config file:

```
[parity]
geth = true
```

and `mist --gethpath $(which parity)` (but [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3077) is currently a blocker).

Comment: What do you need Mist for if you already have Parity? Just use the Parity Browser instead of Mist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mist` GitHub issue [Don't force user to download geth #3078](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3078) indicates that this is not currently possible.

The workaround is to remove `mist`'s `binaries` directory, and then recreate it without read and write permissions.

In Linux:

Remove directory: , then:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Mist/binaries
mkdir -m 000 ~/.config/Mist/binaries
```

This will make the binary directory unwritable, and prevent any download.

Note that non-fatal errors are generated:

```
[2017-09-26 12:37:21.715] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - Unable to resolve Geth executable: geth                                                                                               
[2017-09-26 12:37:21.723] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Download binary for Geth ...                                                                                                           
[2017-09-26 12:37:21.736] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ravi/.config/Mist/binaries/Geth'                                                     
    at Error (native)                                                                                                                                                                         
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:922:18)                                                                                                                                                     
    at Function.sync (/usr/share/mist/resources/app.asar/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/usr/share/mist/resources/app.asar/node_modules/ethereum-client-binaries/src/index.js:230:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)                                              
  errno: -13,                                                                                  
  code: 'EACCES',                                                                                    
  syscall: 'mkdir',                                                                                                             
  path: '/home/ravi/.config/Mist/binaries/Geth' }
```